# How to check incomplete php script execution using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

My php script has to download many image files and script often stops or terminate half way  for number of reasons I'm printing a message (using flush) after every image download and finally a successful completion message

So is there any way if my php script stops before downloading all requested files Then JavaScript somehow check this and print a message?

Comment: Is there a set number of images PHP pulls everytime? If so, you could use Javascript to count the image elements.

Comment: While a PHP script is running, is not possible to access the state of any task. You will need store informations in some place that javascript is allow to access, or to create a second script that return it information for javascript.

Comment: @ssergei No there are no set number of Images

Comment: Does PHP know the number of images before it starts? You could pass this to JS.

Comment: @ssergei No PHP has to filter the list of given set of images during execution, only after succesfull completion it is known how many Images were downloadable

Comment: @ssergei but even if I pass a variable then still question remains i.e when page stops downloading then what is the procedure to check it, My javascript skills are very poor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing such a thing, I recommend you to configure the server to allow the script running as much as needed. Check out [@set_time_limit(0);](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) or check whether your script has bugs/problems.

If you can NOT do these,

**Possible solution:**

Use PHP to add a 'End of Script' tag at the end, wait for page to load, and use JavaScript to check whether the 'End of Script' tag exists at the bottom of the document. It would not find the tag if PHP terminates before reaching the end of script.
Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", function (){
            // Note that the <!--[EndOfScript]--> MUST be exactly same as the one in the end of your document!
            if (document.body.innerHTML.indexOf('<!--[EndOfScript]-->') == -1) {
                alert ("WARNING: PHP has terminated before reaching the end of the script!");
            }
        }, false);
    </script>
  </head>  
  <body>
    <p>Some content goes here. :)</p>
    <?php
      // Your PHP codes here //

      # Change this value to true/false to test the script
      $terminate_test = true;

      if ($terminate_test == true) exit();

      // Place this at the END of your document!
      echo '<!--[EndOfScript]-->';
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

This script works perfectly, change the `$terminate_test` to false to check it out.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking thanks, @set_time_limit(0); doesn't work on certain hosts e.g 000webhost has set script execution limit of 10 sec and nomatter what you do it remains at 10 sec